# Personal Geodatabase not recognized as valid datasource in the last QGIS Windows Weekly build (64 bits)

Tags: qgis, personal-geodatabase

I was using Personal Geodatabases in QGIS without any problem but it's stopped to work since I installed the last 64 bits weekly build for Windows (1.9.0-35-Setup-x86_64). I'm now receiving an "Invalid datasource" error message.

Is this problem related to the last weekly build or specific to the 64 bits version?

**EDIT:**
I confirm that it work on the last 32bit weekly build so the problem is specific to the 64 bits version...

Thanks a lot

Etienne

Comment: I just installed the last weekly build 32bit (1.9.0-35) and opening a PGDB work just fine... the problem is then specific to the 64 bits version.